# Where to find WP_Query class?

Tags: wp-query

I cannot find WP_Query() in my wordpress folder, the global refers to $wp_query but I don't find the class itself. From my wordpress folder, or here directly : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes?order=name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the query.php file. The class is there.

Answer (score 1):

Check this file:

> wp-includes/class-wp-query.php